# Distribute ipa to iTunes connect from command line

Tags: iphone, xcode, bash, xcrun

I have several iPhone apps, and I've set out to do away with as much of the clicking around on iTunes connect that I have to do. One thing that I'd like to do is be able to upload an ipa to iTunes connect through the command line.

[How To Perform iOS App Validation From the Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568420/how-to-perform-ios-app-validation-from-the-command-line)

This post suggests

`xcrun -sdk iphoneos Validation -online -upload /path/to/ipa`

Which almost works, but will fail validation because it tries to hit the first app in iTunes connect, which has a different bundle identifier than the one I'm uploading. So I tried it without validaiton (remove the `-online` flag)

`xcrun -sdk iphoneos Validation -upload /path/to/ipa`

and the still complains about the bundle identifier being separate from the first app available in iTunes connect. Is there a way to pass a bundle, or app's Apple ID, or something into the `xcrun` command to specify an app other than the first one in iTunes Connect? There's go to be a way, and I've tried to get the console output from xCode during an archive/upload action by spawning xCode from the terminal, but it doesn't give me useful information.

Comment: @Marker i am facing the same problem..did you get any closer to the solution

Comment: @Yadnesh what I'm currently doing is, I keep all of my apps out of the "ready to upload" state, and then when I want to upload something I toggle it so that it's the only one. I never found a way to specify an app.

Comment: @Marker  ohh thats sad.. i have almost 20 apps to upload in a queue and i want to completely automate the process

Comment: @Yadnesh it's unfortunate, but you could build a web scraper to go and click the "ready to upload binary" button for you like we did :)

Comment: I've been considering open-sourcing ours, but it has a lot of business-specific logic tied into it right now. I'll let you know if I ever do!

Comment: @MarKer cool...i m really looking forward for that

Comment: sorry to bring up a old post, but has someone a solution directly from command line and not doing a script for clicking on "ready to upload" ?

Comment: I've just answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22987614/1971301

Answer (score 3):

The Apple way to do it is application loader tool: altool --upload-app -f file -u username [-p password] [--output-format xml]

As described here: 
https://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/#/apdATD1E53-D1E1A1303-D1E53A1126

Comment: OK another way to do it is with transporter API:
https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/en.lproj/static.html#apdATD1E1288-D1E1A1303-D1E1288A1126

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still looking for a good solution, check out deliver, an open source library to automate the submission of your app: https://github.com/KrauseFx/deliver

It will use the iTunes transporter under the hood. You can check out the source code of the actual upload here: https://github.com/KrauseFx/deliver/blob/master/lib/deliver/itunes_transporter.rb