# Xcode 7 + Bots + Fastlane: How to automatically deploy an app to itunes connect using Fastlane's Deliver

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, bots, xcode7, xcode-server

**Question: How can I upload an IPA to itunesconnect from a Bot running on Xcode 7 and Server 4.1 using Deliver?**

I've been able to set up a continuous integration solution in with Xcode 6.4, Server 4.1 using bots, and [Deliver](https://github.com/KrauseFx/deliver) (by fastlane). Once I upgraded to Xcode 7 beta-3, my Bots stopped working.

Here is a brief outline of what I did for Xcode 6.4:

1. Select "Perform Archive Action" in Bot Setting
2. From post trigger: echo `gem install --user-install deliver` #Run To Install Gem
3. From post trigger: echo `export PATH=$PATH:/var/_xcsbuildd/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin` #Run to Add Gems to Path
4. From post trigger:

   ```
   echo `DELIVER_PASSWORD="Password"
   /var/_xcsbuildd/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin/deliver testflight 
   "${IPA_PATH}" -a 101233338 -u example@gmail.com --beta`
   ```

Everything worked great and a build was uploaded to itunesconnect after every integration.

When I upgraded to Xcode 7, I was no longer able to upload to itunesconnect with Deliver. Here is my Xcode 7 workflow:

1. Tests Pass
2. Archive successful
3. Post trigger 1: Build IPA Successfully (Using recommendation from [this apple developer post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5626))

   ```
    xcrun xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath 
    $XCS_ARCHIVE -exportPath $XCS_ARCHIVE
    -exportOptionsPlist /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ExportOptions.plist 
    -IDEPostProgressNotifications=YES 
    -DVTAllowServerCertificates=YES 
    -DVTSigningCertificateSourceLogLevel=3 
    -DVTSigningCertificateManagerLogLevel=3 
    -DTDKProvisioningProfileExtraSearchPaths=/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles
   ```
4. Attempt to upload IPA with Deliver:

   ```
   echo `DELIVER_PASSWORD="Password"
   /var/_xcsbuildd/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin/deliver testflight 
   "${IPA_PATH}" -a 101233338 -u example@gmail.com --beta`
   ```

**Result:** 
Build Service Issues: Terminated xcodebuild since it produced no output for too long. 
[image]
Note: I am able to take the IPA's produced by the bot and upload them via the terminal.

### Update

Xcode wasn't printing out all the logs, when I redirected the output into a file it looks like Deliver ran just fine

```
ESC[37m[12:03:08]: ESC[0mESC[32mReady to upload new build to TestFlight (CiTest - 1018099468)ESC[0m
ESC[37m[12:03:08]: ESC[0mUploading ipa file to iTunesConnect
ESC[37m[12:03:08]: ESC[0mGoing to upload updated app to iTunesConnect
ESC[37m[12:03:08]: ESC[0mESC[32mThis might take a few minutes, please don't interrupt the scriptESC[0m
ESC[37m[12:03:08]: ESC[0mESC[32mWaiting for iTunes Connect transporter to be finished.ESC[0m
ESC[37m[12:03:08]: ESC[0mESC[32miTunes Transporter progress... this might take a few minutes...ESC[0m
```

It's just that the xcode server escapes the process before deliver completes.

**Follow-up: Has anyone else experienced this or a similar issue?**

Comment: would love to see an answer for this!

Comment: This is working for me with Xcode 7.3.1, Xcode Server 5.1 and deliver 1.11.2.

Comment: You can use altool as described in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37989546/2559850

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread from apple developer forum:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9812

In case you couldn't open it. Some people said

> It seems that Xcode bot trigger scripts have a 10 second timeout - which is far too short to do any useful work.  I can replicate this by adding a "Before Integration" trigger containing nothing but a call to "sleep 10".  When the integration runs, it fails with the error "terminated xcodebuild since it produced no output for too long".

And possible temp solution could be

> make sure you produce some output when your longer running task is running? Not a fix, but might be a workaround.

And people replied

> I have done this and the error no longer occurs. I was using a bash script and needed to echo the output from time to time to workaround this issue.

Hopefully this will help for the moment.