# xcrun: error: unable to find utility "Validation", not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: xcode, xcode7, ipa, osx-elcapitan, xcrun

The following command used to work before xcode 7

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos Validation myapp.ipa or myapp.app
```

But Now I am getting the above error.

How to solve this bug ? Do we have to install any additional utility ?

or

Is there any way to validate ipa file just like this ?

Comment: Any Luck for far you find?

Comment: Nope ... I am yet to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like it works in Xcode7 anymore, but you can use altool instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34089618/649

Comment: The thing is it requires the internet connection but the xcrun Validation  doesn't require a internet connection.I am looking for a solution that's equivalent to this.