# Xamarin.ios publishing to appstore issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have my xamarin cross platform project, in my xamarin.ios.app, I already have assetcatalog with detached images with specific sizes. But still after uploading the itunes connect it email an error "Missing Asset Catalog - Your app is missing the asset catalog file in 'beamMobile.iOS.app'.". Please help me.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhLwx.png)

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/app-icons/

Comment: I already did the step on that link but still giving the same error.

Comment: run `altool` on your app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34089618/4984832

Comment: it returns "This Apple ID has been locked for security reasons. Visit iForgot to reset your account (https://iforgot.apple.com)" in terminal after using altool

Comment: Can you send me Asset Catalog screenshot?

Comment: wait I have another question. If im going to upload my xamarin.ios to appstore. my bundle id in the xamarin.ios is need to be the same with xcode ?